# Pull facebook friends into my Android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the below code to pull facebook friends into my android app. When I debug it is showing the correct number of friends but it is not able to pull those friends who has logged into the app. As a result the final output is coming empty.

Can anyone go through my code and tell me if I am missing anything in it? I noticed the variable data is always empty but the total count of friends is correct.

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"data":[],"summary":{"total_count":166}}, error: null}

responseObject = {"data":[],"summary":{"total_count":166}}
```

Here is my code..

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends_list);

        final List<String> friendslist2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/friends", null, HttpMethod.GET, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                Log.e(TAG, response.toString());
                try {
                    JSONObject responseObject = response.getJSONObject();
                    JSONArray dataArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("data");

                    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject dataObject = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String fbId = dataObject.getString("id");
                        String fbName = dataObject.getString("name");
                        Log.e("FbId", fbId);
                        Log.e("FbName", fbName);
                        friendslist2.add(fbId);
                    }
                    Log.e("fbfriendList_data", friendslist2.toString());
                    List<String> list = friendslist2;
                    String friends = "";
                    if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
                        friends = list.toString();
                        if (friends.contains("[")) {
                            friends = (friends.substring(1, friends.length() - 1));
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
            }
        }).executeAsync();
`
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_listview, friendslist2); // simple textview for list item
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

The above code is called from the below activity -->`

```
login_button.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult login_result) {
                GraphRequestAsyncTask graphRequestAsyncTask = new GraphRequest(
                        login_result.getAccessToken(),
                        //AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                        "/me/friends",
                        null,
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FriendsList.class);
                                try {
                                    JSONArray rawName = response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");
                                    intent.putExtra("jsondata", rawName.toString());
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                ).executeAsync();

            }
```

Here also 'data' within the rawName is empty but it has the correct count for the number of friends.

Pls note there is one person in my friends list who has logged into the app using facebook credentials so I am expecting that person's details in my app. And I've registered the app with https://developers.facebook.com/apps under main category Games

Anyone's help is very much appreciated..thank you !

Satya

Comment: did both of you authorize the app with user_friends?

Comment: Yes we did. It is working now. I uninstalled the app and installed it and it starts showing the me the list..thank you